# problems exluding categories

Tags: exclude

I have done this before but for some reason, it is not working and I can't figure out why. All I am trying to do is exclude some categories from the blog page. I thought this would be a simple matter. I have the index.php file open, and before my loop, I did this

```
 query_posts( $guery_string . '&cat=-6' )
 if (have_posts)......rest of loop here.
```

I have even tried adding the global $query_string; on top but nothing I do will get rid of category 6. Does this method no longer work in the latest version of wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Don't use `query_posts()`**](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012). Filter [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) instead:

```
function wpse65927_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    // If this is the blog posts index,
    // and if this is the main query,
    // exclude category 6
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-6' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse65927_filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

Put the above hook and callback in `functions.php`. Don't modify any of your template files, including `index.php` or `home.php`, at all.

Comment: I am a little confused on how this would work. I have a file called template-homepage as my homepage. and I have created a page and called it blog. in the settings, I set my site to a static homepage and gave the front page the template-homepage and set the blog page to blog. The blog page is pulling from the index.php file which I modified with a loop so that the blog will look how I need it to look. How would wordpress look at the blog page as home in your filter above?

Comment: That's a nice little function. It works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use just:

`query_posts( 'cat=-6' );`

?

You shouldn't need to re-pass the query string to the index.php template.

Comment: it doesn't work. I tried all those combinations.